# How to access variables of UITabBarController from it's item ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController which has 3 Item subviews:

[image]

I have linked it with a controller swift class and declared certain variables:

[image]

Now I have it's subview which is linked to it with a navigation controller:

[image]

I want to access the above mentioned variables within the subview controller. Please share a Swift 3.0 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your variables are practically globals that have nothing to do with the functionality of a tab bar controller. Following the principle of separation of concerns, you should not store these values in such a controller.

Instead of managing them in the tab bar controller, you could to it in a special class for globals or the app delegate.

Comment: They are not globals. They are instantiated after the login process and are specific to this TabBarView.

Comment: `isUserLoggedIn` is specific to the tab bar view? That's not what a tab bar controller is for. How about a `UserManager`?

Comment: How to define variable with global scope in iOS, so they are accessible in every VC?

Comment: Just define them outside a class.